# How to SIGINT multiple background programs via bash script after a long time?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kill, sigint

I'm trying to write a simple bash script. First, I wrote another bash script where I run 5 copies of two different programs:

```
#!/bin/bash
./fibonacci1 &
./fibonacci2 &
./fibonacci3 &
./fibonacci4 &
./fibonacci5 &
./factorization1 &
./factorization2 &
./factorization3 &
./factorization4 &
./factorization5 &
```

Programs run in infinite loops, and I want to run them for a long time, i.e 10 minutes. I am going to run them on my minix machine and collect some data about my scheduler. The question is, How can I write a bash scrip that kills all 10 programs with SIGINT?

Comment: You could also start the commands with the `timeout` builtin. `timeout 10s sleep 420` for instance will start the command `sleep 420` and kill it if it's still running after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array to capture the background PIDs:

```
#!/bin/bash
pids=()
./fibonacci1 &
pids+=( $! )
./fibonacci2 &
pids+=( $! )
./fibonacci3 &
pids+=( $! )
./fibonacci4 &
pids+=( $! )
./fibonacci5 &
pids+=( $! )
./factorization1 &
pids+=( $! )
./factorization2 &
pids+=( $! )
./factorization3 &
pids+=( $! )
./factorization4 &
pids+=( $! )
./factorization5 &
pids+=( $! )

sleep 600
kill -2 "${pids[@]}"
```

Think about using a loop to start things off, but since you're running 10 different program names, that requires a bit more effort (but not a lot more effort):

```
#!/bin/bash
pids=()
for i in {1..5}
do
    ./fibonacci$i &
    pids+=( $! )
done
for i in {1..5}
do
    ./factorization$i &
    pids+=( $! )
done

sleep 600
kill -2 "${pids[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wasn't able to run your code, There seems to be an error in line 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Are you running it with `bash` or with `sh`. If you use `sh` it probably won't work and is likely to give the error you mention.

Comment: Oh my bad, you're right, running with bash -x foo.sh solved the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, it worked on my Ubuntu machine but not on my Minix machine. It gave the following error for the second code: Line 6: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure as I've not used Minix.  Superficially, it means that the shell on your Minix system is not a modern Bash (where 'modern' means 'from this millennium and not the last millennium', roughly).  It's odd that it's line 6.  If you're using the looping script, that's the `+=` line; if it's the inline code, it is more nearly inexplicable (as line 6 is the second `+=` line, and if there's going to be an error, it should be on the first, not the second).  Again, look carefully at the shell you're actually using.  You may need to run `bash --version` and/or `sh --version` to see what's what.

Comment: Yeah, Minix does have an ancient Bash version, which is 13 years old now. Anyway, I was able to find a "less-fancier" way of coding the script. It works perfectly now. Thanks for all your effort!

Comment: Since arrays are causing trouble, you could go with a plain string for the PIDs: `pids=""` to initialize the list, and then `pids="$pids $!"` to record a new one, and `kill -2 $pids` (with no quotes) to send them all an interrupt. That should work with any shell derived from the Bourne shell since 1980. You might then need to replace `{1..5}` with `1 2 3 4 5` to be certain of working with ancient shells, or with `$(seq 1 5)` if you have the `seq` command and your shells support the `$(…)` notation. Use backticks in place of `$(…)` if necessary.  Using `seq` makes it easy to add more processes.

Comment: oh that's a good solution as well, I just added a new element to the array after running the program, i.e. pids[i]=$! 
this solved my problem I mean it works on my ancient bash as well.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use:

```
command 1 &
...
command x-1 &
ps > tmp
procs=$(tail -n x tmp | head -n x-1 | cut -d' ' -f2) && rm tmp

sleep 420 && kill -2 $procs
```

Where `x` should be substituted by the number of commands + 1. This limits some redundancy but may cause trouble if other commands are called in between the first and last command (which shouldn't happen).

Applied to your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
./fibonacci1 &
./fibonacci2 &
./fibonacci3 &
./fibonacci4 &
./fibonacci5 &
./factorization1 &
./factorization2 &
./factorization3 &
./factorization4 &
./factorization5 &
ps > tmp
procs=$(tail -n 11 tmp | head -n 10 | cut -d' ' -f2) && rm tmp

sleep 420 && kill -2 $procs
```

Comment: `kill -9` is sending SIGKILL, not SIGINT.  It's brutal, too.